# python statistic top 10

Tags: python, list, parsing, dictionary

using python 2.6

I have large text file.
Below are the first 3 entries, but there are over 50 users I need to check.

```
html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 5 38 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34 ... continues
```

I need to beable to find the username in this case the text after the "html_log:" tags

I also need the rating (first set of values next to the username.)

Output would check the entire txt file and output the top 10 highest rated players.

Please note that there are not always 16 sets of values, some contain far less.

producing:

```
bob 1217.1
jeff 1153
fred 28.7
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: What isn't working and where are you stuck?

Comment: Are there any newlines in the inputfile or is it all just one long line?

Comment: Just one long file, I parsed a huge file to make it look like the above but i'm not good with dicts and I can't make the top 10 list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would actually use a regular expression.

Just consider `html_log:` as a record start marker, the next part up until a whitespace is the name. The next part after it is the score, which you can convert to float for comparison:

```
s = "html_log:jeff 1153.3 1.84 625:54 1 2 71 3 2 10 7:58 499 3 5 616:36 241 36 html_log:fred 28.7 1.04 27:34 -10 18 13 0:48 37 18 8 -3.63 html_log:bob 1217.1 1.75 696:48 1 538 6 109 61 14:42 633 223 25 435:36 182 34"
pattern = re.compile("html_log:(?P<name>[^ ]*) (?P<score>[^ ]*)")
print sorted(pattern.findall(s), key=lambda x: float(x[1]), reverse=True)

# [('bob', '1217.1'), ('jeff', '1153.3'), ('fred', '28.7')]
```

Comment: this works then I can just .split and get the first 1:10 in a list :) thanks alot @Thomas Fenzl

Comment: no need to split, the return value of `sorted` is already a list

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering how to read this file the straight forward algorithm would be, first, read the whole file in a string. then use `string.split(' ')` to split everything with space, then through a for loop on every pieces of these check whether an element contains html_log: if yes here is the username, and the next element is the highest rate! and store all these stuffs in a dictionary for further sorting or other operations.

Comment: having trouble working with dicts, I'm not really very familiar with them.

Comment: ok so for having a dic for example a variable named dic you can easily write dic={} to initialize and then for building it simple dic[key]=value